# Settings.bundle issue

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults, root.plist

I experience a problem while accessing my settings. I added a setting bundle to my Xcode project :
[image: Root.plist capture]

I added the following swift code to access the name_preference key :
[image: viewDidLoad capture]

Comment: Always paste the code in a question, not a screenshot of the code. Thanks.

Comment: Please approve an answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UserDefaults crash on missing preference key

Explicit unwrapping is dangerous!: what happens if the string is empty?

**Bad:**

```
let crash = settings.stringForKey("name_preference")!
```

---

**Using `string`:**

```swift
let settings = UserDefaults.standard
if let name = settings.string(forKey: "name_preference") {
    print(name)
}
```

**Using `object`:**

```swift
let settings = UserDefaults.standard
if let name = settings.object(forKey: "name_preference") as? String {
    print(name)
}
```

**Test:** Go to *Settings* and enter a string:

[image: Settings]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-34905431) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-34905431).

Comment: Thanks. You're right, but that doesn't fix my issue. I still can't get the string from Root.plist file.

Comment: Where and how is the `name` variable defined? I have posted a project to demonstrate the response. Download http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-34905431, compile, link, build, run and compare with your own. Also, please post the error in plain text if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! My mistake was I thought the settings in the Root.plist file in my project were synced with the terminal, and they are not. I add to enter some string in the settings and I could catch the same string in my code.

Comment: Sure ! How do you do that ?

Comment: But more importantly, replace the second image by plain text if at all possible.